# time series decomposition error in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have the following dataframe

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
'date': [1988, 1988, 2000, 2005],
'value': [11558522, 12323552, 13770958, 18412280]
})
```

i then make the date column into a datetime dtype

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'],format = '%Y')
```

when i print the dtypes i get

```
print(data.dtypes)

>>> Register No.
>>> date    datetime64[ns]
>>> Sum              int64
>>> dtype: object
```

I then use the following code to make a time series decomposition

```
from pylab import rcParams
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose 
rcParams ['figure.figsize'] = 18,8
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(data, model='additive', freq=30)
fig = decomposition.plot()
```

But i get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-e3a60d7302da> in <module>
      3 
      4 rcParams ['figure.figsize'] = 18,8
----> 5 decomposition = seasonal_decompose(data, model='additive', freq=30)
      6 
      7 fig = decomposition.plot()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/seasonal.py in seasonal_decompose(x, model, filt, freq, two_sided, extrapolate_trend)
    113     nobs = len(x)
    114 
--> 115     if not np.all(np.isfinite(x)):
    116         raise ValueError("This function does not handle missing values")
    117     if model.startswith('m'):

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

i do not have any missing values in my dataframe and im not sure why am getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `date` as index in data frame:

```
data = data.set_index('date')
```

Comment: if i do that i fet the following error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (58,)

Comment: you need to lower `freq` in seasonal_decompose.  Or your time series should be longer.

Answer (score 0):

milos.ai is correct but incomplete. You should indeed set the date as index:

```
data = data.set_index('date')
```

This way, `date.head()` would give:

[image]

But your decomposition should be updated to:

```
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(data, model='additive', period=2)
```

Giving:
[image]